# How to add a specific value to all data by group?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df of CO2 levels from three different sensors (A1,A2 and A3) but each sensor has a different offset. I would like to subtract the known offset (in a separate vector called offSet) from the data and add 400 to all data points in `df$CO2.ppm`.

```
df<-as.data.frame(Sensor=rep(c("A1","A2","A3"),each=50), CO2.ppm.=sample(400:1000, 150, replace=T))

offSets<-as.data.frame(Sensor=c("A1","A2","A3"),value=c(5,6,10))
```

Something like this makes sense in my mind but I can't quite get the syntax of the last bit right. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Sensor) %>% 
  mutate(CO2.ppm.OffSet=CO2.ppm.+400-rep(offSets$value,each=offSets) %>%
  group_by(Sensor) %>% 
  summarise(n()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `dplyr` could be to `left_join` on `Sensor` and perform the calculation

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df, offSets, by = "Sensor") %>%
   mutate(new_col = CO2.ppm + 400 - value)

#    Sensor CO2.ppm value new_col
#1       A1     468     5     863
#2       A1     774     5    1169
#3       A1     766     5    1161
#4       A1     774     5    1169
#5       A1     917     5    1312
#6       A1     784     5    1179
#....
```

and in base R that would be

```
transform(merge(df, offSets, by = "Sensor", all.x = TRUE), 
          new_col = CO2.ppm + 400 - value)
```

---

We can also use `match`

```
df$new_col <- df$CO2.ppm + 400 - offSets$value[match(df$Sensor, offSets$Sensor)]
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
df<-data.frame(Sensor=rep(c("A1","A2","A3"),each=50), 
               CO2.ppm =sample(400:1000, 150, replace=T))
offSets<-data.frame(Sensor=c("A1","A2","A3"),value=c(5,6,10))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is spot on. One slight problem is that  I don't have all the sensors in the first data frame even though the data frame offsets contains all my sensors offsets. Ie. I have another data frame with sensors R1-R3 because they have columns of other data that is not CO2 so can't merge them. So what I'm doing with your answer is manually making the new column: df$new_col=df$CO2.ppm.-df$value to get what I'm after for each df (dfA, dfN, dfR). Is there a generalisable way around this with the current answer? If not I will accept as is and alter my own data frames.

Comment: If `offSets` have all the sensors present in `df` this should work as it is since we want to perform calculations only on `df` and we are using `left_join` here so we will have all the rows of `df` and no additional rows. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you're right but I don't actually have all the sensors corresponding to the ones in offSets in df (I should have said this in the question). For example I only have A1 and A2 in df and A3 somewhere else. I've double checked the code again and it works despite saying they are different lengths. Thank you very much. I will accept the answer and ignore the error as it works anyway.

Comment: Match works a treat with no errors. I apologise for any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a `data.table` join for this

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[offSets, new_col := CO2.ppm + 400 - value, on = .(Sensor)][]
head(df)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(1234)
df<-data.frame(Sensor=rep(c("A1","A2","A3"),each=50), 
               CO2.ppm =sample(400:1000, 150, replace=T))
offSets<-data.frame(Sensor=c("A1","A2","A3"),value=c(5,6,10))
```